# Android - capturing key events with custom keyboards

Tags: android, user-interface, keyboard

I have noticed that with devices that have custom keyboards other than the Android keyboard (e.g. swiftkey or swype), the callbacks onKeyDown() and dispatchKeyEvent() for the activity's main view (that is focused) do not work, or don't guarantee to work.

How can I programmatically and safely capture key pressed from all kinds of keyboards? 
And since I have an openGL surface view I can't really add normal text inputs
like one would in normal apps and save the headache.